# EmptyStackException error

Tags: java

I'm working on a project that solves postfix expressions. I'm having trouble figuring out the exception handling or whether or not I'm event using the stack correctly. Some pointers would be greatly helpful. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.*;
```

public class Solve {

```
int result, num1, num2, stackNum;
MyStack<Integer> stack;
char c;
String expression, delimiter;

public Solve()
{
    result = 0;
    num1 = 0;
    num2 = 0;
    delimiter = " ";
    c = ' ';
    stackNum = 0;
    stack = new MyStack<Integer>();
}

public String evaluate(String expression) throws EmptyStackException
{
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(expression);

    while (st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        //String[] eToken = expression.split(" ");

        try
        {
            //for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); ++i)
            //{
                if (st.nextToken().charAt(0) != '+' && st.nextToken().charAt(0)  != '-' && st.nextToken().charAt(0)  != '*' && st.nextToken().charAt(0)  != '/')
                {
                    stackNum = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                    stack.push(stackNum);
                }
                else            
                {
                    c = st.nextToken().charAt(0);

                    num1 = stack.pop();
                    num2 = stack.pop();
                    if (c == '+')
                        stack.push(num1 + num2);
                    else if (c == '-')
                        stack.push(num1 - num2);
                    else if (c == '*')
                        stack.push(num1 * num2);
                    else if (c == '/')
                        stack.push(num1 / num2);
                }

            //}
        }
        catch (EmptyStackException e)
        {
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
    }
    result = stack.pop();
        return String.valueOf(result);

}
```

}

Comment: What happens when you step through this in a debugger?  When the exception takes place, what are the runtime values?  Clearly the exception means that you're calling `pop()` on an empty stack.  Why does your code think it isn't empty?

Comment: What is `_expression`? E.g. just "+" will obviously immediately throw an EmtpyStackException.

Comment: I have no clue really. I'm giving the code input to push on the stack before I even pop anything off of it.

Comment: Actually, aside from your algorithm being incomplete, I think the problem might be that you're popping the result off the stack before you finish your processing loop.... you never need to pop the result off the stack until you're ready to return your answer. If you pop it early, then the next operator you encounter will have only one operand to work on.

Comment: I moved the last pop() statement outside of the loop and have used a tokenizer to chop up the string and am now getting a NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are not tokenizing your input string. Without separation of the operands via spaces, commas, etc, you cannot tell `"3 4 +"` (which is valid RPN expression) from `"34+"` (which is not). The former is a well-formatted expression, and the latter should cause an error. However, in your code, the former will be evaluated incorrectly (since it tries to add the `" "` character to the stack and add it to things), and the latter will work, but shouldn't.

Comment: The program is to solve POSTfix expressions though. So there HAS to be two integers on the stack before it gets to an operand.